# FF file type blank if you drag files in a folder - DropzoneJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone, react-dropzone

I am using [dropzonejs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-maxfilesreached)/[react-dropzone](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component) and I want to take a folder and drag it in. It should extract the files out, but in FF the file.type is blank and thus all the files get rejected.

I have the basic setup

const config = this.componentConfig;
const djsConfig = this.djsConfig;
const eventHandlers = {
    init: dz => this.dropzone = dz,
    addedfile: this.handleFileAdded.bind(this),
    sending: this.sending.bind(this),
    processing: this.processing.bind(this),
    maxfilesexceeded: this.maxfilesexceeded.bind(this),
    maxfilesreached: this.maxfilesreached.bind(this),
    success: this.success.bind(this)
}

```
this.djsConfig = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    maxFiles: 500
};
    this.componentConfig = {
        iconFiletypes: ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif'],
        showFiletypeIcon: true,
        postUrl: ''
    };

    this.dropzone = null;

   <DropzoneComponent config={config} eventHandlers={eventHandlers} djsConfig={djsConfig}>
```